# Existence of eigenvectors

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices

Let 
$$A(x)=\begin{pmatrix}
\cos x && \sin x\\ 
-\sin x && \cos x 
\end{pmatrix}$$
$x\in(0,2\pi)$. Then:

1.A has eigenvectors in $\mathbb{R}^2\forall x\in (0,2\pi)$

2.A does not have eigenvectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$

3.A has eigenvectors  in $\mathbb{R}^2$ for exactly one value of $x$

4. A has eigenvectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ for exactly two values of $x$.

I tried finding the eigenvalues, but how does $x$ relate to the eigenvectors' *existence*. Am baffled. Thanks beforehand.

Comment: So what have you tried? Have you worked out what the eigenvalues are? Do you know what the matrix represents as a transformation?

Comment: What is your work?

Comment: @EugenCovaci I tried working the eigenvalues but am confused after seeing the *existence* of eigenvectors? How do we prove existence of eigenvectors?

Comment: @vidyarthi You should start with the defiition

Comment: @MarkBennet I think the matrix represents a rotation, is it true?

Comment: @Vidyarthi....I have added an answer. Please let me know how can I help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Hint$: Given matrix is orthogonal with  $e^{\pm ix}$ as its eigenvalues which are real for $x=π\in (0,2π)$